# Can I render simultaneously both with EEVEE and Cycles on the same GPU without perfomance loss?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, gpu, hardware

Recently while rendering in EEVEE and Cycles I had a look on my GPU usage in task manager.

Unsurprisingly when I looked at CUDA usage when using Cycles it was near 100%, while another tab called "3D" was near 0%. But when I then rendered using EEVEE CUDA was at near 0% while "3D" was near 100%.

It appears to me as though EEVEE and Cycles use two completely different areas of the GPU.

Does that mean that I should be able to simultaneously render a scene in Cycles and in EEVEE without experiencing a slowdown in either render?

Comment: Cycles & EEVEE use different sections of the GPU because they are separate. Cycles uses ray-tracing, while EEVEE uses approximate rendering.

Comment: My initial thought is no - the card operates within an input power envelope and probably is throwing all available wattage at the job.  Anything else you give it will divide the available power.

Comment: When rendering, you are doing many things other than strictly calculating the color of each pixel, some of these things require the same parts of the GPU, some of thing things go through the same gate which can't allow any load size nor rate of passage, the list goes on. And even the simple heating of the device by one task does change the performance.

Comment: While I do not have measurements at the moment to back this up, the answer is most likely that you will experience slower rendering. Cycles has to move significant amounts of data to the GPU (e.g. textures and geometry) for the rendering. The possible data rate (bandwidth) creates a bottleneck that determines how fast the rendering can happen. Plenty of resources are shared on the GPU regardless whether OpenGL or CUDA are used. Considering caches, shared local memory, the GPU heating up, the render time per job will most likely degrade.

Comment: However, you might still save time as long as running the jobs in parallel does not cause a slow down longer than running them in sequence. Determining the utilization and performance will require actual measurments on real hardware though and also depend on the particular hardware architecture of the GPU as well as scene complexity.

Comment: Think of it like flatmates: they each have their dedicated rooms but still need to share the same doorway, bills and kitchen.